# opening gnome-terminal and getting its tty programmatically

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, gnome, tty

I am forwarding command from one terminal to the other.
For the moment, I am doing the following

I create the new terminal

```
gnome-terminal
```

I get its tty via

```
w
```

then I can forward commands to it via a python script (found here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10376251/linux-write-commands-from-one-terminal-to-another)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys,os,fcntl,termios
if len(sys.argv) != 3:
   sys.stderr.write("usage: ttyexec.py tty command\n")
   sys.exit(1)
fd = os.open("/dev/" + sys.argv[1], os.O_RDWR)
cmd=sys.argv[2]
for i in range(len(cmd)):
   fcntl.ioctl(fd, termios.TIOCSTI, cmd[i])
fcntl.ioctl(fd, termios.TIOCSTI, '\n')
os.close(fd)
```

this is working well, except that I have to manually get the tty of the new window, which does not work well for encapsulating this in a bigger script. Is there a way for a script to get the tty of the gnome-terminal it opens ?

My solution now is to have the script call "w" before and after call to "gnome-terminal" to infer which terminal has just been opened, but it is error prone.

Comment: Calling `w` is not only error-prone but also no longer works in newer gnome-terminal because it no longer updates the utmp database.

Comment: What's the overall picture? Why do you need such hacks (basically synthesising input into terminals) in the first place? Couldn't you just open a terminal and ask it to run a specific command (or multiple commands combined in a shell script) as in `gnome-terminal -e some_command`?

Comment: You could use `tty` instead of `w`.

Comment: @egmont thanks for pointing the limitations of 'w'. Big picture: we are running a complex system which requires to run command lines to be executed on various computers. Now we open a terminal for each computer, ssh to it, and write commands in suitable terminal. Very error prone ('oops, I wrote in the wrong terminal'). So I am creating a system in which all commands are written in one terminal and forwarded to the terminal connected to the suitable machine, e.g 'execute 'machine_name' command'. 'execute' needs the tty of the terminal that ssh to 'machine_name'

Comment: @Vince this is a very unusual and still heavily fragile approach. Why not have one single shell script which contains command like `ssh machine1 do_this` followed by `ssh machine2 do_that` and so on, having passwordless ssh keys configured if desired?

Comment: @egmont what you suggest was my preferred approach, but I need the outputs from the processes running on various machine not mixed up. Otherwise, I made some test, and what I have now is working perfectly, not getting the tty of the terminal that are opening is the only weak point.

Comment: @Vince "but I need the outputs from the processes running on various machine not mixed up" - yes, ssh is perfectly able to handle this (e.g. redirect to a separate file from each ssh). I guess I'd need to stand by you looking at your screen to fully understand what you're doing. You might say that everything's working for you except one tiny step, but `gnome-terminal` does not support what you're looking for, and you're following a very weird unconventional way of doing things. I would ditch this approach and rewrite from scratch as one single standard shell script that doesn't open terminals.

Comment: @egmont thanks for your input, I do not know the underlying principles so I will trust you on this. I considered using "ssh" with redirection of the outputs to separate files (">>"), but that also requires user to open manually various terminals and run the command for "tailing" all the log files to see what is going on, which is something I want to avoid. I want users to just type "execute machine command" and have the corresponding log displayed on a terminal related to the machine (terminal that opens by itself if not already there). Impossible ?

Comment: @Vince You can open a terminal with a specific program to be executed there, e.g. `gnome-terminal -e 'less /tmp/somefile'`.

Comment: @egmont sorry if I am slow, I sincerely do not get it. After the terminal has opened, how can I send yet another command to it ? I do not want one terminal per command, but one terminal per machine, and send several commands to each machine. For example, "execute machine_name do_this", followed later on by "execute machine_name do_that", do_this and do_that both being executed on machine_name and their output shown on the same terminal.

Comment: @Vince programatically "sending" commands to terminals (injecting keystrokes, if you will) is something that should not be done, nobody does this. Just get this concept out of your head. Instead write a shell script and open a terminal that executes that script. Or you can inline several commands for the terminal's command line, e.g. `gnome-terminal -e 'do_this; do_that'` or similar.

Comment: @egmont no quite what I need. We may need a sequence like 'execute machine_1 do_this', 'execute machine_2 do_that', 'execute machine_1 do_this_other_thing', and we do not know in advances which command will be run in which order. That is up to the user. And the user needs all the output from all command in a readable manner.